I want to add a secondary CIDR let's say to VPC C to create additional subnets
I have a scenario where multiple VPCs, each with a single CIDR range and 3 subnets, are attached to a Transit Gateway, allowing full communication between all VPCs (something similar to the attached diagram).
Now, I want to add a secondary CIDR let's say to VPC C to create additional subnets, but I need these new subnets to only be accessible within VPC C and not announced to the other VPCs connected via the Transit Gateway.
What would be the best way to configure this so that the new subnets remain local to VPC C while keeping the existing communication between the other VPCs intact given that the Transit Gateway is using a single Routing Table ?
Thanks in advance!
I haven't tried anything yet.

Consider to ask sys-admin and networking questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
